# Not able to register node

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I am using below given docker-compose file for setting up the selenium hub-node on my windows 10 machine but I am getting error messages as below:

```
Couldn't register this node: Error sending the registration request: The hub responded with 404
Couldn't register this node: The hub is down or not responding: The hub responded with 404
```

Docker-compose file:

```
    version: "3.9"
services:
 
  hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
 
    environment:
      GRID_MAX_SESSION: 16
      GRID_BROWSER_TIMEOUT: 150
      GRID_TIMEOUT: 150
 
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome-debug
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR: hub
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT: 4444
      NODE_MAX_SESSION: 1
      NODE_MAX_INSTANCES: 4
    volumes:
      #- /src/main/resources/SampleFilesForUpload:/src/main/resources/SampleFilesForUpload

      
    links:
      - hub
 
  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox-debug
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR: hub
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT: 4444
      NODE_MAX_SESSION: 1
      NODE_MAX_INSTANCES: 2
    volumes:
      #- /src/main/resources/SampleFilesForUpload:/src/main/resources/SampleFilesForUpload
    
    links:
      - hub
```

Below are my system details:
OS Name - Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language
Version - 10.0.19044 Build 19044
Processor - Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz, 1800 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)

Please help me out with this issue.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nz81.png